# Quick riddle because I haven't for a while... Hopefully it makes sense even with all the sounds-likes

Tags: riddle, rhyme, language

I was once this until I was no,

I did this just an hour ago,

You'll hear it if you're asked to wait,

or if you're told that you are late.

What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like it could be

> a homophone of *ate* including *eight*

I was once this until I was no,

> Thought here is no in German (language tag) is nein so this sounds like
>
>  You were *eight* before you were *nine*

I did this just an hour ago,

> You ate an hour before

You'll hear it if you're asked to wait,
or if you're told that you are late

> Both wait and late sound like (you'll hear)  *ate*

Comment: Sharp as ever tom.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you might be

> A bell chime

I was once this until I was no,

> One I'm slightly struggling on: It chimes $x$ times before stopping

I did this just an hour ago,

> The clock chimes every hour

You'll hear it if you're asked to wait,

> If you wait for at least an hour you will hear it

or if you're told that you are late.

> Again slightly struggling: If you are asked to a meeting that starts at say 9, and you arrive slightly late the clock will already be ringing

Comment: Sorry.  Not a Bell Chime.  And you're not looking for 'me' this time.  (I know.  Not very traditional!) +1 though

Comment: @BrentHackers ah shame, two of the clues fitted so nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related to being:

> Punctual

I was once this until I was no,

I did this just an hour ago,

> You were punctual as you arrived on time an hour ago.

You'll hear it if you're asked to wait,

or if you're told that you are late.

> If you're early, you're informed you're punctual. If you're late, you're informed that you're not punctual.

Comment: Nope!  +1 for effort and passable fits but the answer requires you to listen a bit more closely and think a little more laterally!